# Не работает предопределение метода в Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Не судите строго, пару дней назад решил вдруг научиться программированию и скачал книгу для детей по Java.
Делаю такое задание:
Создаю класс

```
public class Car {
int distance=0; 
public void start() {
    System.out.println("Я поехал!");
}
public void stop() {
    System.out.println("Я остановился!");
}
public int drive(int howlong){
    distance=howlong*60;
    System.out.println("Проехано уже " + distance + " м");
    return distance;
}
}
```

Создаю класс который буду запускать.

```
public class CarOwner {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Car myCar = new Car();
    myCar.start();
    myCar.drive(3);
    myCar.stop();
}
}
```

При запуске консоль выдает

> Я поехал!
> Проехано уже 180 м
> Я остановился!

Далее создаю подкласс

```
public class BondCar extends Car {
public int drive(int howlong){
    return distance=howlong*180;
}
}
```

Создаю класс для управления подклассом

```
public class CarOwnerBond {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         BondCar myBondCar = new BondCar();
         myBondCar.start();
         myBondCar.drive(3);
         myBondCar.stop();
    }
}
```

При запуске консоль выдает

> Я поехал!
> Я остановился!

Почему не работает override ?

Comment: а почему высчитаете, что у вас что-то не работает?

Comment: Ну такто при написании public int drive(int howlong){
  return distance=howlong*180;
формула должна меняться.
а консоль пишет так как будто эта формула просто пропала

Comment: вообще-то в методе myBondCar.drive не происходит вывод на консоль, а также при его вызове вы никак не используете возвращаемое значение, поэтому вы не видите результата. Однако это не означает, что его нет - метод выполнился вполне успешно

Comment: А почему именно в Eclipse? Думаете, в другом редакторе заработает?

Comment: @VladD думаю, эта фраза многое объясняет: 

>пару дней назад решил вдруг научиться программированию

Comment: Разобрался, благодарю! Какие книги порекомендуете для меня, зная про мои фразы, которое многое объясняют ?

Comment: @LS15 я сам джавой не занимаюсь, поэтому обстоятельно что-то порекомендовать вам не смогу, однако ваш вопрос по книгам довольно частый (вот буквально вчера его тут задавали), поэтому погуглите по форуму (или вообще по интернетам), скорее всего что-нибудь найдете - литературы по этому языку навалом. Веорятнее всего ва посоветуют Хорстмана, Эккеля, Шилдта (или чьи там книги наиболее популярны). Впрочем, по поводу Шилдта есть устойчивое мнение, что он грешит неточностями в своих книгах

Comment: Благодарю!

Comment: Шилдт Java 6. и Философия Java (автора подзабыл). Вторая не для новичков в программировании, так что вам думаю первая получше подойдет

Comment: Думаю, что для новичка подойдет К. Сьерра, Б. Бейтс - Изучаем Java. Затем лучше: Г.Шилдт Java 2. Полное руководство(в этой книге описано очень много и очень много станет понятно как в Java Core, так и в понимании ООП).

Answer (score 1):

Кажется, в вашем методе BondCar.drive нет вывода в консоль.

Comment: комментарии не читай @ сразу пиши ответ